# AVL Tree: Finding the key with the smallest data values in keys between two values in O(logn) time

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, avl-tree

So I'm given an AVL tree.  And im trying to figure out at least the pseudocode to find the key with the minimum data values among all of the keys between two values k1 and k2. This is assuming that the field data stored in each node is an integer. I want to make sure that my pseudocode runs in O(logn) time.

I know that I can do it by storing an extra field in the node structure..and showing how this field can be maintained during updates, but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the node structure looks like this (Java).

```
class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    int key;
    int value;
    int tree_max;
}
```

The recurrence for `tree_max` is

```
node.tree_max == max(node.value, node.left.tree_max, node.right.tree_max),
```

where by abuse of notation we omit `node.left.tree_max` when `node.left` is null and omit `node.right.tree_max` when `node.right` is null. Every time we write to a node, we may have to update all of its ancestors. I'm not going to write the pseudocode, because without a compiler I'll most likely get it wrong.

To find the max between keys `k1` and `k2` inclusive, we first locate the least common ancestor of those nodes.

```
Node lca = root;
while (lca != null) {
    if (lca.key < k1) { lca = lca.left; }
    else if (k2 < lca.key) { lca = lca.right; }
    else { break; }
}
```

Now, if `lca` is null, then the range is empty, and we should return minus infinity or throw an exception. Otherwise, we need to find the max over three ranges: `k1` inclusive to `lca` exclusive, `lca` itself, and `lca` exclusive to `k2` inclusive. I'll give the code for `k1` inclusive to `lca` exclusive; the other two ranges are trivial and symmetric respectively. We move `finger` down the tree as though we're searching for `k1`, accumulating the maximum into `left_max`.

```
int left_max = /* minus infinity */;
Node finger = lca.left;
while (finger != null) {
    if (k1 <= finger.key) {
        left_max = max(left_max, finger.value);
        if (finger.right != null) { left_max = max(left_max, finger.right.tree_max); }
        finger = finger.left;
    } else { finger = finger.right; }
}
```

Comment: So since as I said i was trying to find the minimum instead of the max, it is basically the same as this except the reverse to find the minimum?

Comment: @MangoOfFury Oops, yes.